# Voltage Divider Parallel Circuit

Tags: voltage-divider, homework

I have to find voltage across R<sub>6</sub> but the problem is, i get a parallel circuit in the end, when I solve the circuit i get,

R<sub>2345</sub>=76.67Ω
R<sub>16789</sub>=96.059Ω
To apply voltage divider formula I have to get these resistors in series.
 
I want to know if its even possible to get the voltage across R<sub>6</sub> using the Voltage-Divider formula.

[image]

Comment: Think about this circuit in real-life.  You should soon see that R2,R4, R3, R5 do not matter at all, and can be ignored for this problem.  Plus the answer to your question is yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making the problem more complex than it really is. There is shown that 10V will be across the top of R1 to the bottom of R6. The voltage across R6 will be the same as the voltage across the the combination of R<sub>6789</sub>. So compute R<sub>6789</sub> and then use that value in the voltage divider equation with R1.

There is no need to look at the values R<sub>2345</sub> at all in this problem analysis. They were either put there to confuse you or to be another part of the problem if it was a multipart question referring to the same picture.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY9aHY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even see it from that perspective. This was my first problem which i got this problem. I didn't even knew that some resistors can also be put in the circuit just to confuse.